# Type mismatch. Required Map<String, Any> Found Map<String, Any?>

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, anko

I am trying to execute select using `anko` extension in `kotlin` like below

```
fun read() {
    database.use {
        select(PersonTable.Name).exec {
            select("myTable").exec() {
                parseList(
                    object : MapRowParser<Map<String, Any>> {
                        override fun parseRow(columns: Map<String, Any?>): Map<String, Any> {
                            Log.d("Hello", "Hello")
                            return columns;
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting an error on `return column`

```
Type mismatch. Required Map<String, Any> Found Map<String, Any?>
```

If I change to `override fun parseRow(columns: Map<String, Any>): Map<String, Any>` then it shows an error.

[image]

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.williams.fourthdemo"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-common:0.10.1"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sqlite:0.10.1"
}
```

Is this bug in the anko library ?

Comment: Don't know if it is a bug or not. But to get around this you can map `columns` to a new `Map<String, Any?>` and then return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like

`object : MapRowParser<Map<String, Any>> {`

should really be

`object : MapRowParser<Map<String, Any?>> {`

It is very common for databases to have columns that return a null in the cell. The way you defined it as `Any` means null is never going to happen. If you cast your return to a `Map<String, Any>` then you will simply end up with runtime errors happening if a null is contained anywhere.

You are best suited by making it an `Any?` type which forces the parseRow return type to be `Map<String, Any?>` as well and fixes the potential bug in your code that would happen if a null value were to creep up somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

`columns` has type `Map<String, Any?>`, note that `Any?` is whatever object or `null`. But method's return type is `Map<String, Any>`, `Any` can't be null.

For example, you may filter incoming map, leaving only non-null values: `columns.filterValues { it != null } as Map<String, Any>`. It contains an unchecked cast, but it's safe.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug in Anko. It's a bug in your code.

This function is wrong:

```
override fun parseRow(columns: Map<String, Any?>): Map<String, Any> {
    Log.d("Hello", "Hello")
    return columns;
}
```

You are taking an input and returning it as-is but with a different type.

Your input is of type `Map<String, Any?>` but you have to somehow transform it into `Map<String, Any>`

It would be as if you defined a function that takes String and returns Int like this:

```
fun parseString(s: String): Int {
    return s
}
```

This will obviously not compile.

The interface you're trying to implement is basically:

```
interface MapRowParser<out T> {
    fun parseRow(columns: Map<String, Any?>): T
}
```

You're supposed to provide a function that converts a dictionary representing a database row, to some concrete object of your choosing. But you have to actually provide code to do the processing.

Alternatively, Anko provides you a function that can automagically match a table row to a class constructor, which is what I would prefer to use, instead of doing a manual mapping of dictionary keys to class fields.

```
data class User(val userId: Int, val userName: String)
val rowParser = classParser<User>()
```